# Android RecycleView: Adding dynamic views

Tags: android

I have decided to upgrade my code to use RecyclerView now instead of the list I am using now.

As I understand the following is how it normally goes:

- onCreateViewHolder - this inflates a view, and does the findviewbyid and returns it as a ViewHolder object for the view
- onBindViewHolder - this assigns the view holder values to the position view (which is being recycled).

This is all fine and dandy... If the views in the list contain the same fields...

My views however in my list are different, before I programmatically added views depending on the adapter List (in the getView method).

Is there a "good practice" way to handle this, I can't think of a good way to get around this.

getViewItemType does not work as the views are unique and that they are not predefined.

Comment: Did you know about getItemViewType()?

Comment: @Varundroid Oh I did not good Sir! I will look into it immediately!

Comment: @Varundroid After looking at the direct description of it, it seems like this is what I'm looking for! I will update my question (or answer it) depending in my findings.

Comment: What do you mean by views are independent?

Comment: @Varundroid I have a list in which every element contains another list (multidimensional array you can say). So every view is unique!

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need to use when you different types of Views inside a ListView or RecyclerView :-

```
getItemViewType() and getViewTypeCount()
```

First you need to use getViewTypeCount() and return the number of unique views you need inside your List. Then override getItemViewType() and return the View type you want to inflate inside the List row.

Hope it will help.

If you still have any issue and need a working example, let me know, i'll update my answer.

Comment: I looked further into it and as you describe they are predefined views unfortunately, my views are created depending on the data making them unique to every view! In other words I cannot inflate views, it must be done programmatically. Hope your answer helps others though!

Comment: Yes, you can still do it. Have a separate xml based on how many number of view you need to inflate as ListView items. If you have ridiculous amount of totally different types of views than I would recommend to use LinearLayout inside ScrollView. There is no point of having ListView when views aren't the same at all because ListView does a good job when the Views are repetitive so it can recycle them.

Comment: Ahh so you suggest I implement a custom system, hmm I shall look at this, makes sense now when you mention it.

Comment: No matter how dynamic your Views are you can still create them in xml and inflate based on the criteria using if, else and fill them with values inside the getView method.